# Flutter/Dart won't display FutureBuilder snapshot when resolved

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I'm attempting to set a field value from SharedPreferences like so:

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: _getUsername(),
              initialData: 'Bruh',
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                print(snapshot);
                print(snapshot.data);
                print(snapshot.hasData);
                return snapshot.hasData ? TextFormField(initialValue: snapshot.data, onChanged: _setUsername) : TextFormField();
              }
            ),
```

This is the _getUsername() future I'm using:

```
Future<String> _getUsername() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
return prefs.getString('username') ?? 'hmm';
return "Fine";
}
```

And this is the console output:

```
Reloaded 0 of 567 libraries in 352ms.
I/flutter (28961): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.done, tesy, null)
I/flutter (28961): tesy
I/flutter (28961): true
```

As you can see, L2 of the output shows 'tesy', which is the value in SharedPreferences, but I only ever see 'Bruh' in the text field (the initial value).

In all the examples I can find, 'Bruh' would be displayed (extremely) briefly (if at all) before 'tesy' is then displayed in the input box. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you do full reload as well, or only hot reload?

Comment: @ookami.kb just tried a full reload, and the problem persists. I can't spot any reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change

```
TextFormField(initialValue: snapshot.data, onChanged: _setUsername)
```

To

```
TextFormField(key: UniqueKey(), initialValue: snapshot.data, onChanged: _setUsername)
```

This is because TextFormField is "Stateful" and the widget tree doesn't detect the change, puting a unique key, does the job that you want, another option is update value using an TextEditingrController.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is in `TextFormField` itself. When the component is being rebuilt, changed `initialValue` is not taken into account. If you want to have a "dynamic" initial value, it's better to provide an explicit controller. Something like this:

```dart
class TestApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestAppState createState() => _TestAppState();
}

class _TestAppState extends State<TestApp> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.text = 'Initial';
    _initUsername();
  }

  Future<void> _initUsername() async {
    final username = await _getUsername();
    _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(text: username);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: TextFormField(controller: _controller, onChanged: (_) {}),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String> _getUsername() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    return 'Loaded';
  }
}
```